# Don't understand the const method declaration

Tags: c++

Too much C# and too little C++ makes my mind dizzy... Could anyone remind me what this c++ declaration means? Specifically, the ending "const". Many thanks.

```
protected:
     virtual ostream & print(ostream & os) const
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, for editing it for me. :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `const` method will simply receive a `const` `this` pointer.

In this case the `this` pointer will be of the `const ThisClass* const` type instead of the usual `ThisClass* const` type.

This means that member variables cannot be modified from inside a `const` method. Not even non-`const` methods can be called from such a method. However a member variable may be declared as `mutable`, in which case this restriction will not apply to it.

Therefore when you have a `const` object, the only methods that the compiler will let you call are those marked safe by the `const` keyword.

Comment: unless the members are tagged mutable

Comment: Minor nit:  *this will be const in a const method.  The this pointer is always const, regardless of whether or not the method in question is const.

Comment: @Void: Yes, but it will be of the `const ThisClass* const` type rather than of `ThisClass* const` type. Added this to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The ending `const` means that the `print` function shouldn't be able to change the state of any of the members of the class it is declared in (and therefore cannot call any member functions of that class which are not also declared `const`).

In the example below, the `print` function in the class `Foo` cannot change any of the member variables of `Foo` (unless they are declared `mutable`), and cannot call any non-const functions in `Foo`.

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(string value) { m_value = value; }
protected:
    ostream & print(ostream & os) const {
        m_value = string("foobar"); // won't compile
        os << m_value;
        return os;
    }
private:
    string m_value;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The `const` on the method declaration tells the compiler that the function is safe to call on a const object of the type the function is a member of. It also signals to the compiler that the function is not supposed to alter the state of the object and it will not be able to change any member variables that are not marked as `mutable`.

If you omit the const, this code will not work:

```
const Foo bar;
bar.print(std::cout);  // Will fail to compile unless 'print' is marked const
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a protected virtual method named `print` which takes as a parameter a reference to an ostream and returns a reference to an ostream.

The const keyword means the method won't be able to alter the state of the object, the `this` pointer will be const.

A virtual method is a method whose behavior can be overridden within an inheriting class, basically the virtual keyword gives C++ its' ability to support polymorphism.

And finally if you don't know what is a reference [go there](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ref.html#fqa-8.1)

Comming from C# I suppose you know what protected means :)